# Error of List<T>.RemoveAt()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
lock("data"){
    if(_requestList.Count>1 && _requestList[1]==null){
        Debug.Log("why0");
    }
    _requestList.RemoveAt(0);
    if(_requestList.Count > 0 && _requestList[0] == null){
        Debug.Log("why1");
    }
    doSomething ();
}
```

`_requestList` is a List of string

Sometimes it logs "why0", sometimes "why1", and sometimes both, and sometimes nothing.

The elements added is never null.

So why?

Comment: log contents of `_requestList` and see what's going on there

Comment: can you tell what value _requestList is having in each case ?

Comment: why are locking using "data" instead of some shared variable?

Comment: Don't lock on a string, create a local private object and lock on that instead.

Comment: You're locking a string defined inline. Each thread will have it's own instance of that string and thus different references to lock, which in turn results in race conditions occurring within your critical section, making the `lock` pretty much useless here, even though it's necessary. You should lock a shared reference-type variable instead (one that can be accessed by all relevant threads)

Comment: Thank you all very much, I'll try.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you need to use a

```
private readonly object lockObject = new object();

lock(lockObject)
{

}
```

You also need to put a `lock(lockObject)` around anywhere where you are adding to the list.

Hope that helps in some regard.

You could also look into a [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) if you don't want to worry about threading.

Comment: +1 for suggestion of ConcurrentBag for a robust thread-safe implementation.

Comment: Still not work, but thank you very much. I'll track the detail. In unity3d, there's only .NET 2.0. So I can't use ConcurrentBag, o(╯□╰)o